# BCryptPasswordEncoder bean not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In my SecurityConfig I have a BCryptPasswordEncoder bean being declared but it is not being picked up by Spring.  I'm running Intellij as the IDE, and Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE.

Here is my SecurityConfig file:

```
package com.microservices.security.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
    }

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            "/api/auth/**",
            "/register",
            "/users/**",
            "/refreshToken",

    }; 

     @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Here is my main file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient

public class LoginServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoginServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

I've tried putting the PasswordEncoder Bean definition in the main class as well and also in the Controller class to no avail.  I've looked at the other answers and none of them seem to help.

Comment: You defined type of your `passwordEncoder` bean as `PasswordEncoder`, however the dependency requires bean of type `BCryptPasswordEncoder` - that is the reason, sometimes `spring` may "infer" real bean type from `@Bean` annotation, sometimes (usually) it fails.

Comment: I got it.  I created a class called 'PasswordEncoder' and put the Bean in there and it works.  Thanks!